# Placed a file on S3 Using boto and IAM ARN

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I have to placed a file on s3 bucket(Owned by B) using boto and IAM ARN from Server(Owned by A).
Access_Key and secret key is not available . I just have arn

Please Help

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you have and try to achieve? The ARN is for IAM role that you have to assume to upload your objects?

Comment: I have below requirement 
dump data into s3 using iam role chain.can you please share the iam role, we will give permissions to your role and you can dump the data.
Eg role: arn:aws:iam::840785816044:role/RedshiftCopyUnload
How can i create this role and can i get the python script to upload file after creating role?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `A` is an account and `B` is another account. To put a file to S3 you need to use `assume-role`.
In `A` you need to assume the role using given `role-arn` and make AWS CLI or SDK call.
Here is the reference for AWS CLI: [assume-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html)

Comment: I have below requirement dump data into s3 using iam role chain.can you please share the iam role, we will give permissions to your role and you can dump the data. Eg role: arn:aws:iam::840785816044:role/RedshiftCopyUnload How can i create this role and can i get the python script to upload file after creating role?

Comment: Use [https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role](this link to see how boto3 assume_role API to use with Role ARN).

Comment: Either you can create a role on AWS Console or you can ask your admin to create a role on your behalf but be sure that you allow 'sts:AssumeRole' in IAM policy.

Comment: You can add something like this in you IAM policy:
`{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Action":"sts:AssumeRole","Resource":["arn:aws:iam::840785816044:role/RedshiftCopyUnload"],"Effect":"Allow"}]}`

Comment: Thanks !
After creating role Arn , how can i place file on s3 using boto?